# Push notification not received in ios 6 and ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push-notification

Push notifications are received badge number is increase and the sound is played or there is vibration, but I am not able to see the notification in top banner or not see the alert. saw the settings they are proper. I tried by changing both alerts and notification but only sound is there. 
Please help.

Comment: How are you sending them? From a PHP script? RoR? Manually?

Comment: have you added this option while registering for push notifications? UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert

Comment: Post what you're using to send, that way we can see if there's an issue.

Comment: yes have added option for registering push notification, it was working properly till ios 5.0 now in 6 and 7 it is creating problem so data from php server is sent properly, the thing is that the data gets updated and badge number  increases, sound is played but it is not showing in banner list or not showing alert when in background, when app is in foreground it shows alert

Comment: please post the payload (the entire JSON data) which you are sending and let us know if your app is in background or foreground ?

Answer (score 1):

In your php script you missed

```
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
        'badge' => 1
)
```

Alert tag that's why you got sound and badge number but not able to show notification. And also please check your application notification setting.

Comment: **And also please check your application notification setting.** Why?

Comment: I checked the php script alert tag is sent :( , also in settings I tried for both banner and alert but don't know what is wrong

Comment: @Anjani can you post your php script here.